# Passing expected Exception into assertThrows: JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit, assert

I have a function that throws many different exceptions based on the input

```java
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("EncodeInvalidDataGenerator")
    public void TestInvalidEncode(CName input, Class<?> expectedException) {
        var baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        assertThrows(expectedException, () -> input.encode(baos));

    }
```

Is there a way to do something like the above? Currently the first parameter of `assertThrows` is the wrong type.

Is this even good programming practice?

Comment: The first parameter of `assertThrows` is bounded by `Throwable`. Your `expectedException` is not.

Comment: "Is this even good programming practice?" Probably depends on the number of different exceptions which can be thrown. If they are only a few and the situations in which they are thrown are similar the code _might_ be better readable and maintainable if the test method was split into multiple test methods testing the different exception types (therefore not having the exception type be a test method parameter).